# How to make waveplot nicely displayed using librosa with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, librosa

Referring to this link: https://aqibsaeed.github.io/2016-09-03-urban-sound-classification-part-1/, I am trying to make the same waveplot figure, however, I got the figure as this: [image: Waveplot].

I am running these python codes:

```
def plot_waves(sound_names, raw_sounds):
    i = 1
    fig = plt.figure()
    for n, f in zip(sound_names, raw_sounds):
        plt.subplot(10, 1, i)
        librosa.display.waveplot(np.array(f), sr=22050)
        plt.title(n.title())
        i += 1
    plt.suptitle("Figure 1: Waveplot", x=0.5, y=0.915, fontsize=18)
    plt.show()
```

Any idea how to improve to achieve the same figure as shown in the link? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From the link you posted, the `plot_waves` function is copied below.

Note the `figsize` and `dpi` parameters passed to `plt.figure`. The `figsize=(25,60)` specifies the (width, height) of the figure. `dpi` of course specifies the resolution. Using these parameters will increase your figure size and resolve the "squished" look that seems to be the problem.

Since your figure title overlaps your first axis title, you'll also want to specify parameters for the position of the title in `plt.suptitle`. Not that the `x` and `y` values in `plt.suptitle` are fractions of the image size from the left and bottom, respectively. So `x=0.5` specifies a title position in the middle of the figure horizontally and `y=0.915` specifies a vertical position of 91.5% of the total figure height from the bottom of the figure.

Always feel free to play with these settings until you get a plot that looks right to you.

```
def plot_waves(sound_names, raw_sounds):
    i = 1
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,60), dpi = 900)
    for n,f in zip(sound_names,raw_sounds):
        plt.subplot(10,1,i)
        librosa.display.waveplot(np.array(f),sr=22050)
        plt.title(n.title())
        i += 1
    plt.suptitle("Figure 1: Waveplot",x=0.5, y=0.915,fontsize=18)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I am not taking the sample code especially for fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,60), dpi = 900), because, it threw out exception: _tkinter.TclError: not enough free memory for image buffer. There are two issues for me: 1). suptitle squished look. 2) subplots figures are overlapping with each other. Unable to try to figure out the suitable parameters.

Comment: Try getting rid of the `dpi = 900` argument and using `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,60))` instead. It sounds like you are trying to load too much into memory for your machine, and the dpi setting is unimportant if you just want to look at the image on your screen. Issue (1) will be resolved by adjusting the y-position in `plt.suptitle` as I discussed above. If `y=0.915` doesn't work, try `y=0.93` and so on. Issue (2) will be resolved by increasing the height of the figure relative to the width using the `figsize=(width, height)` argument.